# Alter data with pattern matching for python strings

Tags: python, string, replace, substring, pattern-matching

I'm doing my bachelor thesis and I need to visualize data with python / jupyter. Now I'm facing the problem that the .txt file I got is *nearly* executable in python but not completely.

What I'm doing now is just reading this whole file as a string and after that I manipulate is such that it is executable with exec().

Yes I now, that's critical but since I am working on a virtual machine and I now that this data is not malicious I decided to do it like this.

The remaining problem is that I get lists like this:

```
sample = [[0 0 0 0 0]
          [0 0 0 0 0]
          [0 0 0 0 0]
          [0 0 1 0 0]]
```

and I need to add a comma to get a list like:

```
sample = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I found re.sub() which seems helpful but I'm wondering how.
The 'lists' are now stored as a string.

I would be grateful for any advice :)

Hints for the correct function to use or maybe the use of this function would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you fix the file you're trying to read _at the source_? If the file comes from another script that you have written, you should consider writing the output in a format that is easily deserialized, such as json or pickle.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. I use IBM CPLEX to solve a problem and actually I have those commas in my CP-code and it just don't want to print them......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file contents are in a string called `file_contents`, you can use

```py
file_contents = re.sub(r'](?!=])', '],', file_contents)
```

to add a comma after each `]` not followed by another `]`.
Similarly,

```py
file_contents = re.sub(r'(?<=\d) (?=\d)', ', ', file_contents)
```

will add commas to the spaces surrounded by digits.

Comment: Thank you! I just added this and it works (partly). Do you have an idea how to design a regex to set a comma between the numbers?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Editing the post now.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! Since I am new, I have no privileges to upvote your answer but I will come back! :D